# Import IBM Timestamp using BCP?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ibm-midrange, bulkinsert, bcp

Is there a direct way to import an IBM timestamp in the format 2008-01-30.22.44.22.435894 using BCP into SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise datetime2 field?

I have files being delivered from the AS400 and the bulk loads are failing on the timestamp columns.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one is answering I'm going to assume its not possible.

I decided to just bulk load it into a varchar so it can be converted later.